# curl_easy_perform() in libcurl returns code 2

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I'm using curl_easy_perform() in c++ to make http calls. I do the following initialization

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/lecture/add_sensor_data");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "course=course1&session=session1&task=task1&acceleration=2");
```

and I run `res = curl_easy_perform(curl);` in a timer loop(10 times a second). I noticed that for the first 700 http calls curl_easy_perform would return a 0 and then it starts to return 2(CURLE_FAILED_INIT) frequently. I'm trying to fix this issue so that curl_easy_perform returns only a 0. Any input would be helpful.

I'm running a web service locally on my machine and making the http calls using curl from c++ application.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html), did you try using [`CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html) to get a human readable error message explaining why it failed?

Comment: I've set the -v flag by `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);` I noticed the error message **easy handle already used in multi handle**. I just added a lock around the `res = curl_easy_perform(curl);` so that only one thread can access the the curl handle and I don't get the return code 2 anymore.

Comment: The [libcurl thread safety guidelines](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html) could be a good read then...